# Como pegar o Texto de uma Div Class e Colocar dentro de uma Label?

Tags: vb.net, div, label

Estou tentando pegar o "valor" dentro da div para colocar dentro de uma Label.

**Div:**

```
<div class="info">valor</div>
```

**Primeira Tentativa**

```
Variavel1 = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("info").GetAttribute("innerText")

Label1.Text = Variavel1
```

**Segunda Tentativa**

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("class") = "info" Then
       Variavel1 = Element.GetAttribute("innerText")
       Return
    End If
Next

Label1.Text = Variavel1
```

**Descobri que na página existe várias classes "Info"...**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Esse código funcionou, porém trouxe outro resultado, além do esperado...**

```
    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Div")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("info") Then
            Variavel1 = (curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText"))
        End If
    Next

Label1.Text = Variavel1
```

**O resultado foi o valor dessa Div que também tem a classe "info".**

```
<div class="msg"><div class="info">OMG/BTC and OMG/ETH  OmiseGO markets added</div>
```

Comment: Se você possui várias div´s com classes chamadas "info" fica dificil definir qual a "info" você quer trazer, pelo código seu que funcionou, apenas a última será armazenada, já que dentro do foreach percorre-se todas as div´s que chamam "info".

Answer (score 0):

O que você precisa fazer é utilizar uma query xpath pra selecionar especificamente o nodo que você quer.

[Esta pergunta do StackOverflow em inglês mostra como usar xpath com o WebBrowser do .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355386/using-xpath-and-webbrowser-control-to-select-multiple-nodes)
(está em C#, mas dá pra entender tranquilamente).

Caso você não saiba utilizar xpath, [veja esta documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).